# using python netmiko to save h3c switch config and meet the no more

Tags: python

Guies:

I used python with netmiko module to save the configuration from our h3c switch,but it stopped at the "NO MORE" status, and the script stopped until timeout.

Answer (score 0):

line vty 0 4
  screen-length 0

^_^